# How to add a value of a dynamic javascript variable in a function name that is in an another variable

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to add a value of a dynamic JavaScript variable in a function name at the `<a href>`.

For Example:

```
var x =  document.getElementById('example').value // value is 6 now
<a href="javascript:function6();">+</a>
```

with `document.write` it should look like this:

```
document.write('<a href="javascript:function"' + x + '();">Something</a>'
```

The issue is, that I have to use inner.html.

I have such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function count(){ 
       var x = 1;
       document.getElementById('count').value = ++x;  
       var z = x + 4;
   }

   var ex = ("<a class=\"button6\" href=\"javascript:anotherfunction\" + z + '()'>Anything else<\/a>");

   function new(){
       document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += ex
   }
</script>
<table id="add">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="button6" href="javascript:new();count();">+</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The "+"-link should add an another link with the counter value in the function name at the href just like this:

```
<a class="button6" href="javascript:anotherfunction6();">+</a>
```

The first "+"-link in the code should add an second link with the counter value in the function name at the href, so after clicking the "+"-link two times the added code should be like this:

```
<a class="button6" href="javascript:anotherfunction6();">+</a>
<a class="button6" href="javascript:anotherfunction7();">+</a>
...
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: May I ask *why* you need this? What are you trying to achieve by having "numbered" functions? Also, putting JavaScript into the `href` attribute is bad practice.

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: `new` is a keyword in Javascript, and can't be used as an identifier.

Comment: When you edit your post, make sure you are not reverting the useful edits by other users...

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? I mean; why do you need a html element call a dynamically generated function? Maybe if I know why there is a better way to design the solution.

Comment: also if the function name is not "new" it doesn't work

Comment: look here bit.ly/13uRE55

Answer (score 0):

`\" + z + '()` should be `" + z + "'()`. There are other problems with your code though, so "doesn’t work" may have several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code.. i see you havn't escaped your codes properly..

try this

```
var ex = ("<a class=\"button6\" href=\"javascript:anotherfunction\"" + z + "'()'>Anything else<\/a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you should fix:

1) Escape sequence.

```
`var ex = '<a class="button6" href="javascript:anotherfunction' + z + "()\">Anything else<\/a>";`
```

2) Function name. `new` is a keyword and could not be used as a function name.

3) Variable scopes. Variable `z` should be visible to both functions and variable `ex` should be set every time you are creating new reference.

After all fixes the code looks like:

```
var z = 0;
function count() { 
    var x = 1;
    document.getElementById('count').value = ++x;  
    z = x + 4;
}

function createButton() {
    var ex = '<a class="button6" href="javascript:anotherfunction' + z + "()\">Anything else<\/a>";
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += ex
}`
```

Also, you should fix your HTML code:

```
<a class="button6" href="javascript:createButton();count();">+</a>
```

P.S. Using javascript in <a> is a bad code style. Generating a bunch of functions like `anotherfunctionN` is also is not a good idea.

Comment: by clicking "New Category" there should appear the same row as below, but the "+"-button doesn't appear

Comment: Escape sequence of `anothercategory` variable is not correct. It should look like `href=\"javascript:add_product_categorie" + z + "()\">+</a></td><tr>"` at the end. Well... anyway, there's much refactoring to be done.

Comment: the "+"-button appears now in the new rows, but the value of variable z is not saved in the href of the new "+"-button. When you mouseover the new "+"-button it's always addproductcategory0, but the alert after clicking "New Category" returns the right counter value

Comment: ok, now I fixed this too, I had just to put the variable with the html as its value in the function and not as global variable. Thank you guys !

Comment: glad, you looked at the answer more carefully :)